# Understanding logic tile LC_5 bits

Tags: yosys, ice40

i m new to yosys and arachne-pnr. Here is the snippet from .asc and .icebox_explain. I could not understand how the bits of LC_5 are derived from .logic_tile 1 11.

example.v

```
module top (input a, b, output y);
  assign y = a & b;
endmodule
```

example.asc

```
.logic_tile 1 11
    000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    000000000000000101000000000000000000000000000000000000
    000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    000000000000000000000000000000011000110000000000000000
    000000000000000000000000000000001110110000000000000000
    000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    000000000000001111000000000000000000000000000000000000
    000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

icebox_example.asc

```
   .logic_tile 1 11
LC_5 0000000000001111 0000
buffer local_g0_4 lutff_5/in_3
buffer local_g3_0 lutff_5/in_2
buffer neigh_op_lft_4 local_g0_4
buffer sp4_h_r_24 local_g3_0
```

How, LC_5 0000000000001111 0000 is generated from this stream?

```
Given in documentation:
LC_5 B10[36] B10[37] B10[38] B10[39] B10[40] B10[41] B10[42] B10[43] B10[44] B10[45] B11[36] B11[37] B11[38] B11[39] B11[40] B11[41] B11[42] B11[43] B11[44] B11[45]

I guess it should be:

B10-36:45=1100000000
B11-36:45=1100000000
```

which is not correct. Can you please help and guide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LC_5 isn't the LC_ bits directly, but the 16 LUT init bits followed by 4 flipflop config bits.

The mapping from these to LC_ bit index is another step, also described in http://www.clifford.at/icestorm/logic_tile.html right at the bottom.

Comment: OK. You mean ".param LUT_INIT 1111000000000000" from example.blif is linked to ".logic_tile 1 11
LC_5 0000000000001111 0000" in example_explain.asc file.
Then what do the bits B10,36-45 and B11,36-45 bits points to?

Comment: B10,36-45 and B11,36-45 are the ultimate bitstream bit indexes, in the logic_tile array in the asc.